# Удалить файл из коммита, который был отправлен (git pull) на сервер

Tags: git, git-push, git-filter-branch, git-rm

Волей случая, и моей неосторожности, попал в репозиторий тестовый файл довольно большого размера, который не должен был туда попасть. Заметил я это, когда начал делать push на сервер.

В общем, в репозитории у меня появился каталог files, в котором этот тестовый файл, и куча других все так же, ненужных файлов.

В общем, нагуглил несколько решений:

http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/intl/ru/ch05.html

http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/2-permanently-remove-files-and-folders-from-git-repo

http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/intl/ru/ch05.html

Меня интересует **вопрос**, после инструкций, приведенных по этим ссылкам, файл удаляется из истории, но при этом размер репозитория остается таким же, как и с этими файлами в индексе. ЧЯДНТ? Или так и должно быть, файлы, однажды добавленные в индекс, физически остаются в репозитории навсегда?

После этих операций вывод команды git status будет таким:

```
: git status 
В ветке dev
Your branch and 'origin/dev' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
нечего фиксировать, рабочая директория пуста
```

Т.е. имеем расхождение в одном и том же коммите на сервере и у меня. **Вопрос**: как мне мою версию с удаленными из истории файлами запушить на сервер?  )

Comment: Для удаления файлов в истории нужно использовать git filter-branch. Для принудительного пуша какого-то конкретного состояния репы можно использовать git push -f.

Comment: Без принудительного пуша "удалить навсегда" файл не получится.

Можно откатиться у себя, а потом запушить это состояние принудительно. Но если с вами в компании работают и другие люди, то они не обрадуются (им придется делать принудительный pull).

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно удалить файл только из удаленного репозитория воспользуйтесь командой

```
git rm --cached mylogfile.log
```

Для удаления каталого из удаленного репозитория

```
git rm --cached -r mydirectory
```

После этого закоммитьте и запушьте изменения в репозиторий. В локальном репозитории файлы останутся, а из удаленного удалятся.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем уверен, сработает ли это для удаленного репозитория, но попробуй [это](https://blog.truecrux.org/post/ix).

```
rm -rf .git/refs/original && git gc --aggressive
```